# accentColor is deprecated flutter 2.5

Tags: flutter

I use `accentColor` property, i get that this attribute is deprecated. how can i create an specific accent color using the new way?

**the code is:**

```
 theme: ThemeData(
            accentColor: const Color(accentColor),
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```dart
 theme: ThemeData(
      colorScheme:  Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(secondary: Color(accentColor))
),
```

for more info check their doc

https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/theme-data-accent-properties

```dart
final ThemeData theme = ThemeData();
MaterialApp(
  theme: theme.copyWith(
    colorScheme: theme.colorScheme.copyWith(secondary: myColor),
  ),
  //...
)
```

Code before migration:

```
Color myColor = Theme.of(context).accentColor;
```

Code after migration:

```
Color myColor = Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary;
```

Comment: thanks for answering, but i have been seen this article, i just need to assign this attribute as secondary: Color(accentColor) without creating `final ThemeData theme = ThemeData();`

Comment: It's written in the top, check it

Comment: `theme: ThemeData(
      colorScheme:  Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(secondary: Color(accentColor))
),`

Comment: i think it would be better if i use the same variable 'theme' better than instantiating a new object in every field, thanks @Al.Sarie